# Passing PDO object into class - PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am refactoring a (procedural) PHP Library I wrote a while back into a lightweight OOP framework. I'm getting caught up with trying to pass a PDO object to be used in a class. Here's what I've got so far.

**Config.php**

```
<?php

class Config {
    // Database Variables
    private $db_type;
    private $db_host;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_pass;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_path; // for sqlite database path
    private $db_char; // charset

    // Site Variables
    private $s_protocol;
    private $s_subdomain;
    private $s_domain;
    private $s_tld;
    private $s_dir;
    private $s_name;
    private $s_description;
    private $s_path;
    private $s_visibility;
    private $s_pipe;
    private $s_apps;
    private $s_hooks;
    private $s_blocks;
    private $s_assets;

    // User Default
    private $u_groupid;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->set($config);
    }

    public function set($config) {
        if (!empty($config) && is_array($config)) {
            foreach ($config as $k => $v) {
                if (property_exists(get_class($this), $k)) {
                    $this->$k = $v;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }

    public function get($config) {
        if (!empty($config)) {
            return $this->$config;
        }
    }

    public function domain() {
        return $this->get('s_protocol') .'://'. $this->get('s_domain') . $this->get('s_tld') .'/'. $this->get('s_dir');
    }
}
?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php

class Database extends PDO {
    private $config;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
        switch($this->config->get('db_type')) {
            case 'mysql':
            case 'pgsql':
                try {
                    return new PDO(
                                $this->config->get('db_type') .':dbname='. $this->config->get('db_name') .';host='. $this->config->get('db_host'),
                                $this->config->get('db_user'),
                                $this->config->get('db_pass')
                    );
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case 'sqlite':
                try {
                    return new PDO($this->config->get('db_type') .':'. $this->config->get('db_path'));
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case 'firebird':
                try {
                    return new PDO(
                                $this->config->get('db_type') .':dbname='. $this->config->get('db_host') .':'. $this->config->get('db_path'),
                                $this->config->get('db_user'),
                                $this->config->get('db_pass')
                    );
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case 'informix':
                try {
                    return new PDO(
                                $this->config->get('db_type') .':DSN='. $this->config->get('db_name'),
                                $this->config->get('db_user'),
                                $this->config->get('db_pass')
                    );
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case 'oracle':
                try {
                    return new PDO(
                                'OCI:dbname='. $this->config->get('db_name') .';charset='. $this->config->get('db_char'),
                                $this->config->get('db_user'),
                                $this->config->get('db_pass')
                    );
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
        }
    }


}
?>
```

**Auth.php**

```
<?php

class Auth {
    // Set Database object
    protected $db;

    // User fields in users table
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $displayname;
    private $groupid;
    private $ip;
    private $created;
    private $updated;
    private $cookie;
    private $sessionid;
    private $lastlogin;
    private $token;
    private $active;

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->db = $dbh;
    }

    public function add($params) {
        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO
                `users` (
        ';
        $cols = array_keys($params);
        $col_string = implode(', ', $cols);
        $sql .= $col_string .'
                )
            VALUES (
        ';
        array_walk($cols, function(&$v, $k) { $v = ':'. $v; });
        $col_string = implode(', ', $cols);

        $sql .= $col_string .'
                )
        ';
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);

    }

    public function remove($params) {

    }

    public function update($params) {

    }

    public function get($params) {

    }

    protected function set($params) {
        if (!empty($params) && is_array($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                if (property_exists(get_class($this), $k)) {
                    $this->$k = $v;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
}

?>
```

**init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$params = array(
                'db_type' => 'mysql',
                'db_host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'db_user' => 'user',
                'db_pass' => 'password',
                'db_name' => 'database',
                'u_groupid' => 4
            );
require_once('Config.php');         $c = new Config($params);
require_once('Database.php');       $db = new Database($c);
require_once('Auth.php');           $u = new Auth($db);

$user = array(
    'email' => 'newperson@email.com',
    'password' => md5('password'),
    'firstname' => 'Jeff',
    'lastname' => 'Wilson',
    'displayname' => 'Jeff Wilson',
    'groupid' => $c->get('u_groupid'),
    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'sessionid' => session_id(),
    'active' => 1,
);
$u->add($user);
?>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in Auth.php on line 46

This is line 46:
`$stmt->execute($params);`

As far as I know I'm passing the PDO object to the Auth class correctly. It shouldn't say it's a non-object. Can anyone else see what's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like `$this->db->prepare($sql)` failed and the pdo instance isn't set to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION -> $stmt "is" FALSE.

Comment: @VolkerK - I have added these settings and the page still throws a 500 Internal Server Error and checking the http log it still says the same thing - PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in Auth.php on line 46.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the pdo instance is set explicitly to use exceptions for error reporting you have to check the return value of [PDO::prepare](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
if ( !$stmt ) {
    // prepare failed
    // the array returned by $this->db->errorinfo() most likely contains more info about the error
    // don't send it unconditionally,directly to the browser, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A6-Sensitive_Data_Exposure

}
else {
    $result = $stmt->execute($params);
    if ( !$result ) {
        // not ok
    }
    else {
        // ok
    }
}
```

edit: I can leave out the first part of my answer, since Alex Ivey already [wrote it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980650/4833). ;-)

Just image behind the scene php is doing something like

```
function __internal_newDatabase() {
    // just image the parser/compiler creates this function
    // from your class defintion
    $instance = array(
        'properties'=>array('config'=>null),
        'methods'=>array('beginTransaction'=>PDO::beginTransaction, 'prepare'=>PDO::prepare, ...)
    );  
    // some magic function that calls a method and "replaces" $this by the second parameter
    invoke(Database::__construct, $instance);
    return $instance;
}
```

and when your script contains `new Database` instead it calls `__internal_newDatabase()`. That's (ooooversimplified) what happens and therefore you can *not* just "change" the instance within your constructor "method" by returning a different instance. Your constructor is supposed to make *this* instance fly (or bail out by throwing an exception).
Your class Database is derived from PDO, i.e. it is supposed to behave as a PDO. In other languages that implies that the/a base class' constructor *must* be called. PHP doesn't enforce that. But in this case leaves your Database instance unusable. You have to explcitily call the parent's constructor as Alex's answer shows.

But there are other issues with this class. (First a confession: I'm biased as can be against `class Database`. In *virtually all* in all cases it's just wrong and therfore automagically raises a red flag for me)
Foremost: Given its name and the way you use it, it's superfluous. It's just a configuration detail not a class derived from PDO. More likely it would be a factory and/or something within an IoC container (if you use that).
On the other hand it might not be just a configuration detail but might (and probably will) cause different implementions for different databases. PDO is not a database abstraction, just a unified access layer.
Your class Auth.php doesn't care about the concrete sql dialect used - and this particular query will most likely work for all database systems supported by PDO. But there will sooner or later be queries that have to be customized for the different RDBMSs. And then your base class would probably be called something like `DB_Adapter` and there would be `MySQL_Adapter extends DB_Adapter` and so on....

Comment: When I put this in it does not give me a 500 Internal Server Error - but checking the http logs it throws this: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Database::$errorinfo

Comment: errorinfo isn't a property but a method returning an array. see http://docs.php.net/pdo.errorinfo

Comment: Ah ok right! My apologies. This is what is returned in the http logs - PHP Warning:  PDO::errorInfo(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called

Comment: Oh, now the question gets interesting ;-) ...because I only skimmed over the code. Your class `Database ` extends PDO and when you call $this->prepare() it actually calls PDO::prepare but _this_ instance hasn't been initialized properly (...because you can instantiate derived classes without calling any constructor of the base class; one of my less liked "features" of php). I'll edit the answer, but the summary is: Database::__construct isn't supposed to do something like `return new PDO(...`, it is already working on the instance that is to be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor in the Database class is returning a value (a PDO object). The `__construct()` function should not explicitly return a value. Since your Database class extends PDO, call the parent constructor instead:

```
parent::__construct(
    $this->config->get('db_type') .':dbname='. $this->config->get('db_name') .';host='. $this->config->get('db_host'),
    $this->config->get('db_user'),
    $this->config->get('db_pass')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your Database class

```
   public function getConnection() {
        return new PDO(
            $this->config->get('db_type') .':dbname='. $this->config->get('db_name') .';host='. $this->config->get('db_host'),
            $this->config->get('db_user'),
            $this->config->get('db_pass')
        );
    }
```

call prepare statement like this:

```
$conn = $this->db->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Your $conn has to be `PDO` object in this case

The main problem here is while `$db = new Database($c);` seems to be fine at the first glance, calling `$db->prepare` is not good because `$db` is instance of `Database`, but has to be instance of `PDO`

One of the ways to improve a bit connection handling would be:
In your `Database` class to have a `private $conn` for connection

```
class Database extends PDO {
    private $config;
    private $conn;

     public function __construct($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
        switch($this->config->get('db_type')) {
            case 'mysql':
            case 'pgsql':
               try {
                    $this->conn = new PDO(
                        $this->config->get('db_type') . ':dbname=' . $this->config->get('db_name') . ';host=' . $this->config->get('db_host'),
                        $this->config->get('db_user'),
                        $this->config->get('db_pass')
                    );
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }

            break;

         // ...

        }
    }
```

THEN in the same class new method to return connection:

```
public function getConnection() {
        return $this->conn;
    }
```

AND FINALLY call it:

```
$this->db->getConnection()->prepare($sql)
```